# apps cannot be opened in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, dual-boot

I have a hp pavilion 14 laptop that comes with windows 11, I recently installed ubuntu and dual booted it. After installation and getting into the desktop, i can open apps like calculators and sudoku but i cannot open firefox or any apps that I install in the ubuntu software. When I click the icon in the desktop it opens a new window and spins but after a while its gone, I tried opening the app via terminal but I got no response from it and when I tried to close it, it says that the terminal is still running, I waited for an hour but still no response, what should I do?

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; it sounds like Ubuntu Desktop but its helpful if you're specific, and please provide release details. Did you make any changes in last session when it worked?  eg. changes to python3 versions & other core components can create problem like this that don't appear until the next session.  I'd likely try and open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal & try running an app from there (eg. type `firefox` to start firefox) as messages can be helpful, though some apps provide more detail than others (*firefox isn't the most helpful I find*)